# Can ribbon balance load between multiple endpoints?

Tags: netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I have a Zuul+Ribbon gateway application.

I have a legacy service running on `localhost:8081`
and a new service running on `localhost:9000`

There is a Find Item by ID API on both services, however on the legacy one its URI is

```
localhost:8081/foo/item/{id}
```

whereas on the new service it is

```
localhost:9000/bar/items/{id}
```

I want to direct 90% of the traffic to the legacy service, and 10% to the new service. I understand this is possible if they both had an API endpoint at the same URI.

However is it possible to load-balance between two different URIs?
If yes, what does the ribbon config look like for that?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the incoming request to Zuul have the same URL?